# Explained variance threshold for eigenfaces

Tags: variance, pca, python, supervised-learning, threshold

I was working through creating a simple face recognition system by first creating eigenfaces. At the very end of [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface), it mentions that the first three principal components are due to lighting variation and should be disregarded. My question is, if we drop the first three components, what is the correct way to rescale the variance explained by the remaining components?

So for example, if I want use `n` components that explain $95\%$ of variance, and I was considering the first 3 components then I can do this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_lfw_people

#Note that this next line can take many minutes the first time you run it as it needs to download ~200MB
lfw_people = fetch_lfw_people(min_faces_per_person=30, resize=0.4)

pca = PCA().fit(lfw_people.data)
explained_variance = np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
n = sum(explained_variance <= 0.95)
```

This results in an `n` of `150`. Now if I disregard the first three components I get

```
explained_variance[150] - explained_variance[2]
```

an explained variance of only $53\%$. So my question is, it is reasonable to just rescale the $\%$ variance explained to be the percentage of the remaining components (i.e. excluding the first three) so something like:

```
explained_variance = np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_[3:]/sum(pca.explained_variance_[3:]))
```

Or is it not that simple?

Comment: Not sure understand what you want to do. Variance explained quantifies how much of the variance in the original signal is captured by the components you've selected. Do you want to do something like choose the components that account for 95% of the remaining variance after discarding the first 3 components?

Comment: @user20160 yes exactly. Basically, what is a sensible way to choose how many components to keep after discarding the first three? Do I need to use cross validation or can I normalise it as above and keep enough such that they explain 95% of variance in 'features' not in 'lighting'